# Problem with manually editing a textbox bound to a property that's continuously updated

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a textbox bound to a property. The property continously gets updated from a timer. What I'm trying to do is to make it so that when I'm in the middle of typing something in the textbox, the textbox should stop updating itself from the property. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a WPF or databinding expert, so there may be a better way, but I'd say you'll have to handle the GotFocus and LostFocus events and add/remove the databinding in those event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something in the order of:

```
  public void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs eArgs)
  {
    if(!Textbox.GotFocus())
    {
          // Regular updating of textbox  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `Binding` object, you could set its `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `Explicit`, which will prevent automatic updates.

**EDIT**

Perhaps something like this

```
UpdateSourceTrigger old;

protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Binding b = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);
    old = b.UpdateSourceTrigger;
    b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Binding b = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);
    b.UpdateSourceTrigger = old;
}
```

Of course, this is short form, without any null checking etc.

Comment: Hmmm. Your idea combined with Max Schmeling's suggestion might be a good lead to a solution.

Comment: Well, it doesn't sound too hard to add GotFocus and LostFocus handlers in which you would set this property on a retrieved Binding object.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this previous StackOverflow question helpful: [.NET --- Textbox control - wait till user is done typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671728/net-textbox-control-wait-till-user-is-done-typing). You should be able to modify that fairly easily to do what you need.