# How would I get a numeric up down to wait until user is finished typing?

Tags: .net, numericupdown

Almost the same question as [.NET --- Textbox control - wait till user is done typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671728/net-textbox-control-wait-till-user-is-done-typing)

but it is for a [numericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(VS.80,lightweight).aspx) which says on the textChanged event:

> (This event supports the .NET
>   Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your
>   code.)

. I want a user to be able to type a number and if another key is not pressed after an interval (500ms for example) the valueChanged event fires (or a custom method call is made).

I'd really rather not go back to using a textbox with a vscroll bar, hopefully there is a way or... the MSDN warning isn't justified for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ValueChanged.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28d=lightweight,v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using value changed, however the valueChanged doesn't fire unless the user tabs out, hits enter, or otherwise shifts focus. i'd like the user to be able to enter a value, see what happens, and then continue typing/editing if they don't like what they see/get