# Is there any VB.Net event who does the same of VBA "AfterUpdate"?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, updating

I need to do something after a `TextBox` has changed.

If I use the `TextChanged` event the code run on every char inserted or deleted.

Googling I found a suggest [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22775163/AfterUpdate-equivalent-event-in-VB-NET.html) using a `String` variable to store value of `TextBox` and using `Enter` and `Leave` events.

Is it the only (or the better) way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want to update some other thing after the text changed has been **finished**.
updating some thing other on every keystroke/textchanged event might be expensive.

for that you can use timer to detect wether the user is continuing with keystrokes or has paused.

example

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
            TimerUserTypingDone.Stop()
            TimerUserTypingDone.Interval = 400    ' duration to wait till concluding that typing by user is finished, and get results
        TimerUserTypingDone.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimerUserTypingDone_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerUserTypingDone.Tick
        TimerUserTypingDone.Stop()

    UpdateWhatsoEverRequired()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something lighter.

Comment: Can you be more specific about requirements.

Comment: Using Enter and Leave is pretty simple. I was asking if is there a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two options :

1 Using the `Enter-Leave` pattern.

This way you save the text value when you enter in the `TextBox` and you compare the new value when you leave it.

```
Private _originalText As String 'To remember the text

Private Sub MyTextBox_Enter(Sender As Object, e As EvventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.Enter
  'When we enter the TextBox, we save the text value
  _originalText = MyTextBox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub MyTextBox_Leave(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.Leave
  If MyTextBox.Text <> _originalText Then
    'The text has changed
  Else
    'The text has not changed
  End If
End Sub
```

2 Use a Timer that will detect when user is done typing.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671735/5897829), the idea is to give the user half a second between two key strokes. If we are within this timer, we wait again to signal the text has changed.

Comment: The other solution is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/671735/5897829), and resumes what @pankaj did.